# Django can't identify which input field is being pressed

Tags: python, html, django, django-forms

I can't seem to recognize the problem in my django project - I have a simple form with 2 "input" tags and I can't identify in my code which one is being pressed.

front end:

```
<form method="POST">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <input type="image" value="accept" class="v" src="{% static 'main/assets/icons/v.png' %}">
    <input type="image" value="decline" class="x" src="{% static 'main/assets/icons/x.png' %}">
</form>
```

back end:

```
if response.method == "POST":
    if response.POST.get("accept"):
        return render(response, "main/calender-page.html", {})
    if response.POST.get("decline"):
        return render(response, "main/account-page.html", {})
```

I tried to search for answers in stack overflow and I never managed to find one that works.
Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2):

add name='accept' and try again:

```
<form method="POST">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <input type="image" value="accept" class="v" name ="accept" src="{% static 'main/assets/icons/v.png' %}">
    <input type="image" value="decline" class="x" name="decline" src="{% static 'main/assets/icons/x.png' %}">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

you need html tag attribute 'name' to identify POST data key.

Answer (score 0):

i think u need radio input.

front end:

```html
<form method="POST">
    {% csrf_token %}
<input type="radio" name="accept" value="1" >
    <img class="v" src="{% static 'main/assets/icons/v.png' %}"/>
</input>
<input type="radio" name="accept" value="2" >
    <img  class="x" src="{% static 'main/assets/icons/x.png' %}"/>
</input>
</form>
```

back end:

```
if response.method == "POST":
    if response.POST.get("accept") == "1" :
        return render(response, "main/calender-page.html", {})

    elif request.POST.get("accept") == "2":
            
        return render(response, "main/account-page.html", {})
    else:
        #other
        return render(request, "main/error-page.html", {})
```